# Acquire formula from experimental values

Tags: regression, modeling

I have a set of values from which I wish to acquire a formula. Below is the data set.

```
F         V1      V2      V3      V4
A1(i)     0.02    30      0.5     X1(i) 
A2(i)     0.02    60      0.5     X2(i)
A3(i)     0.02    90      0.5     X3(i) 
A4(i)     0.02    120     0.5     X4(i) 
A5(i)     0.1     30      0.1     X5(i) 
A6(i)     0.1     60      0.1     X6(i) 
A7(i)     0.1     90      0.1     X7(i) 
A8(i)     0.1     120     0.1     X8(i) 
A9(i)     0.2     30      0.01    X9(i) 
A10(i)    0.2     60      0.01    X10(i) 
A11(i)    0.2     90      0.01    X11(i) 
A12(i)    0.2     120     0.01    X12(i) 
A13(i)    0.5     30      0.02    X13(i) 
A14(i)    0.5     60      0.02    X14(i) 
A15(i)    0.5     90      0.02    X15(i) 
A16(i)    0.5     120     0.02    X16(i) 

F = cutting force,
V1 - V3 = cutting parameters
V4 = Position of the tool.
```

I need a formula for Y as a function of V1, V2, V3, V4. Where V1, V2, V3 are the process parameters in a mechanical cutting process, and V4 is the position of the tool while cutting. What we observe is that, even when the process parameters (V1, V2, V3) are constant we get different values of A for every X depending on the tool position on the workpiece.

Is it possible to have a formula for this? I already have used regression analysis to get a formula for a max value of A as a function of V1, V2, V3. But now I would also like to include the changing values of X (position variable) and the resulting A values there from to get another formula.

I have seen other similar questions but I still feel that this is a different case hence I have created a new question.

The signal which I use to measure the force looks like this:

[image]

it can also be represented by the following formula (found using matlab curve fitting toolbox)

$$
f(x) = k \left(a_1  e^{-\left(\frac{x-b_1}{c1}\right)^2}+
            a_2  e^{-\left(\frac{x-b_2}{c2}\right)^2}+
            a_3  e^{-\left(\frac{x-b_3}{c3}\right)^2}+
            a_4  e^{-\left(\frac{x-b_4}{c4}\right)^2}+
            a_5  e^{-\left(\frac{x-b_5}{c5}\right)^2}\right)
$$

does anyone hav an idea as to how to create a regression model for this equation, given tht i have 16 sets of values, one each for each of the 16 variables $$ k, a_1,b_1,c_1,....a_5,b_5,c_5 $$

Comment: To format a table in $\LaTeX$ you start with \begin {array}{r l r l r} to put five columns right and left justified, put & between columns, \\ at the end of a line, and finish with \end {array}.  Put it all in double dollar signs and you are there.

Comment: I need some help interpreting your data.  Clearly (from edits) the middle three columns are V1-V3, and the outermost are supposed Y and V4.  However, I'm not clear on what values Y and position take, or if they're even supposed to take values.  Are each of the X$i$ discrete positions of the tool?  And how should we interpret each of the A$i$?

Comment: @DrewChristianson - Yes you are absolutely right about which variable is which. Y takes values which are dependent on the process parameters and the position of the tool Xi. As the tool the advances, the value of Ai changes, but the process parameters remain the same. Each Xi are discrete positions of the tool. Xi has values which increase continuously and Ai first increase and decrease. pls get back to me in case there is any doubt.

Comment: I guess I'm just not clear on either on the data or what you're asking.  You say you vary the X$i$ while holding the process parameters constant, but the data looks like there is a different set of values for V1,V2,V3 for *every* X$i$.  If you do have data on many different process parameters for every X$i$, you can include each of the different positions as a categorical variable in a MLR.  Alternatively, if the positons can be well-ordered, (i.e. we're talking left-right vs discrete $(x,y)$ positions) it may be possible include position as a variable.  It's not clear from the question

Comment: what data you actually have, or what form it takes.

Comment: The table is now readable, but still incomprehensible. In particular, the columns are not labeled. In the body, you write of $Y$ as depending on four variables, $V_1,V_2,V_3,V_4$, and then you also write about some other variable $A$ which depends on yet another variable $X$; all told, 7 different quantities. But the table only has three columns of numbers, and it's not at all clear what these are. If you want anyone but yourself to understand what you are on about, you are going to have to put much more thought into your exposition.

Comment: I guess you're not getting it, and that's understandable.  The longer you work on a problem, the harder it is to see it from an outsiders perspective.  The problem I have is with the 'data' in columns for Y and V4. It's essentially meaningless to someone attempting to read the table. You might as well have listed the numbers 1 through 16 in both columns; that's all the information you've given us.  As I said in my pervious comment, it would be much easier to help you if you display your data as completely as possible.  Show the values for Y and V4 and we will be able to help

Comment: A thought: If they're protected under NDA, data with identical pattern but different values would be sufficent to get a feel for the problem

Comment: I took the liberty of tweaking your equation to make it easier to read. Please ensure it still says what you want it to say. If not, you can rollback w/ my apologies.